# Probability of $2$ out of $10$ student wearing spectacles

Tags: probability

It is known that $40\%$ of students wear spectacles.  From a sample of $10$ students, calculate the probability that exactly $2$ students wear spectacles.

I tried $0.4^2 \cdot 0.6^8$, which is two  students wear spectacles times $8$ students did not wear spectacles, where $0.6 = 1-0.4$.

But the answer is not correct.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange, it is expected that you tell us what you have tried in order to solve the problem rather than just typing up the problem with no attempts visible. Thanks

Comment: Hint: $any$ 2 students

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're leaving out the binomial coefficient term of the [probability mass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Probability_mass_function) when doing your calculation.

$Pr(X = k) = {n\choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$

Take what you have and multiply it by ${n\choose k}$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

What is $p\{X=2\}$ if $X$ follow a $\text{Binomial}(10,2/5)$ ?